# How to retrieve and display a JSON object in a REST client?

Tags: json, node.js, rest

I am attempting to learn node and JavaScript. I have implemented the use of a node module that retrieves train journey times.

I can retrieve and display the times within the command line but i cannot display in the RESTFUL client. Does anyone have any advice on how to display all the movies within the RESTFUL client?

```
//GET ALL TRAIN TIMES
router.route('/train_times')

//get all the times (accessed at GET http://localhost:8000/api/times)
.get(function(req, res) {

    cw.times(function(err, res, json){

        var times = json.train;

        //It is here i try and display the train times
        res.json(times);

        for (index = 0; index < time.length; ++index) {
          console.log(time[index].data);
        }

    }); 

});
```

Comment: Seems like you are doing everything correct. Does the console log the correct data? Are you accessing the correct url? I see you comment /api/times, while the actual route seems to be /train_times.


Edit:

Never mind, I see you have res.json(times) outside of your cw.times callback, that means that times is undefined when res.json is called; Move res.json into the callback and it should work.

Comment: The first console.log works correctly - it is the res.json(times) that i am using to attempt and display the retrieved times within the client. Yes i see the route is different to the URL - i simplified the names when creating the question, my apologies.

Comment: I edited my comment before you answered, please test the res.json problem I indicate :)

Comment: @Stian i have moved res.json(times) inside the callback and attempted to run the code which gave the following error - 'res.json is not a function'. I hope i moved it to the correct position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the call back function reused the name of the variable `res`. Try to use a different name:

```
cw.times(function(err, response, json){

    var times = json.films;

    //It is here i try and display the train times
    res.json(times);

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. I am new to both node and JS so find it quite hard to understand what exactly is going on at times.I really appreciate your help!